# Firefox 11 sync with Android device

Tags: firefox, android, firefox-sync

I've just installed Firefox 11. I'd like to sync it with the one on my Android device. I tried to follow the instructions they provided and tried to pair device. I entered the code from Android to desktop. This made my phone show a window showing 'Waiting for device' and a progress bar running all over again.

Than I tried to use 'I'm not near my computer' option on Android.  I am asked for email, password and a recovery key. So I googled a little and found an [instruction](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-manage-my-firefox-sync-account#w_where-can-i-find-my-recovery-key).

I go to Options/Sync. But there are only 2 options:

- Set Up Firefox Sync
- Pair a device

So how can I get this recovery key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. It was strange. After I deleted and created the account again. All the sudden magically the Sync tab got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever used Firefox Sync to synchronize bookmarks between two Firefoxes before? I remember that when I created my Firefox Sync account (then it was called Mozilla Weave) I was given a "Sync key" which looks like this:

fpaqw-uxqcv-cbtwx-ptzsw

The problem is that the page with this key is probably shown to you only right after the registration of the account. I'm not sure how it works now, hope it helps!